# Why @click is not working on h1 tag in vue js

Tags: html, vue.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vue js 01</title>
    

</head>
<body>
  <div >
    <h1   id="message" @click="update">{{message}}</h1>
  </div>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <script>
        let app = Vue.createApp({
            data(){
                return {
                    message:'hai welcome to vue 3!',
                 }
            },
            methods:{
                update(){
                 this.message='Changed'
                }
            }
        })

        app.mount("#message")
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**why this is not working when click on h1 tag**
when I am clicking this h1 tag it is not working. but if it is inside a `<div>` it will be work moving it id to this div